# laravel progress bar how to define output

Tags: php, laravel-5.4

i am trying to use `Laravel progress bar` from https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/artisan

but i am getting the following error

```
 (1/1) ErrorException
Undefined property: App\Http\Controllers\ImportDeviceController::$output
```

following is my code:

```
    $users = \App\Users::all();

    $bar = $this->output->createProgressBar(count($users));

    foreach ($users as $user) {
        $this->performTask($user);

        $bar->advance();
    }

    $bar->finish();
```

**Updated:**

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Input;
use App\Http\Helpers\GlobalHelper;
use Illuminate\Support\Collection;
use App\Http\Helpers\ImportDeviceHelper;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Redirect;
use App\Http\Controllers\ImportController;
use Excel;
use XmlParser;
use Storage;
use Symfony\Component\Console\Helper\ProgressBar;



class ImportDeviceController extends Controller
{

    public function __construct(Request $request)
    {

        $this->objGlobalHelper = new GlobalHelper;
        $this->objImportDeviceHelper = new ImportDeviceHelper($request);
        $this->objImportController = new ImportController($request);
    }

    /**
     * Display a listing of the resource.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */



    public function device()
    {
     $users = \App\Users::all();

    $bar = $this->output->createProgressBar(count($users));

    foreach ($users as $user) {
        $this->performTask($user);

        $bar->advance();
    }

    $bar->finish();


    exit;
 }
```

Comment: Post the full context - what does `$this` refer to?

Comment: If you are using an instance of `ImportDeviceController` or a method of this class through **Dependency Container**, then you must to pass its instance through the ``__constructor()``

Comment: i am just trying to follow the progress bar example from here https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/artisan i have nothing else in that controller

Comment: ok. i have updated it.

Comment: Progress bar works in controllers too? Thought it would only work for artisan commands. Edit: at least for me the progressbar works perfectly fine in my artisan commands

Comment: ohhh i was thinking might be for front end so i can put dynamic progress bar until i upload the file on the server? so this is different? what should i do then? i want a progress bar on HTML end

Comment: It's a nice progress bar for your artisan commands, which is CLI. Don't know of any HTML progress bar, sorry.

Comment: @Muhammad recommended to close and open new question asking for a progress bar inHTML

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because @francisco told me to close and reopen it.

Answer (score 0):

i don't know if it's still worth answering but i see this post and i've just had the same issue/question before a colleague had the kindness to explain it to me : all the console/terminal methods are available only in the handle method of a console command script.
In my case, i wanted to apply this progressbar method in a controller and this is why "output" wasn't defined !
The idea is to use a support or a command or service decorrelated from any route and call it into a command script, then you will be able to use command methods such as progressbars
My explanations may not be very accurate/clear but i hope it can help someone ^^

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -1):

```
use Symfony\Component\Console\Helper\ProgressBar;
use Symfony\Component\Console\Output\ConsoleOutput;
$output = new ConsoleOutput();
$progressBar = new ProgressBar($output, $totalCarData);
```

> //now you can use the default way using command anywhere in laravel

```
$progressBar->start();
```

Comment: please read comments. user don't want anything with console. just html.